# Extjs Form Panel Structure

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

Using Extjs4.1, I need to know what is the best approach to create a login page within a website? i created a form panel but it appears above white background which i don't know how to deal with. as in here:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/EugeneDae/hWGYE/`
```

i want the panel ppears above a background covering the whole page. i have to mention that the website is based on Viewport, while the login page is separate from it.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Ext.window.Window({
    items:addUserForm,
    modal:true
}).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/xuCQN/